# Having troubles with Auto layout - why do I get errors for adding a label under a stack view?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, stackview

I am currently working through the 'App development with swift' book and am trying to do the 'Apple pie' project. I have been following directions and after doing (What I think) are the same things the book tells me to do, I am getting errors. So I'm hoping someone can explain to me why the errors below are appearing.

**Project before adding label to bottom of vertical stack view:**

[image: Project before adding label to bottom of vertical stack view]

**Project after adding label to bottom of vertical stack view:**

[image: Project after adding label to bottom of vertical stack view]

**Errors received:**

[image: Errors received]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the height on the label to 60 and that Alignment 'Centre' is selected in the attributes inspector.

Also make sure the parent StackView is on Alignment: Fill, Distribution: Fill.

Comment: Jeez..thank you. Feel like an idiot, I was so sure it was in there for some reason. Appreciate it.